# GNUPLot: scale and plot data to specific range

Tags: plot, gnuplot, scale

I want to plot a data set to a specific range. So if for example my data has 1000 rows, then I want to plot the whole data to an xrange 1:5. Now I can't to this with the set xrange command because this simply would plot the first 5 rows, but I want the whole data scaled down to the 1:5 range. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

As @sweber pointed out, you may actually talk about rows but not columns.
You can get the number of records (rows) using the command `stats 'datafile.dat' using 1`.
The variable `STATS_records` reports the total number of in-range data records. In addition, you can get the maximum (STATS_max) and minimum (STATS_min) of the x axis.
Type `help stats` to see more information.